# Lightweight message queue to use with Celery 4.0

Tags: python, django, celery, message-queue, messagebroker

I'm currently using Celery 3.1 in a Django project on Python 2.7.

So far, we were using the Django ORM as a broker for development and staging environments. That was convenient, because you could pretty much just check out the sources, install the dependencies, run the migrations and `celery worker` would just work out of the box.

I'm thinking about how to set that up after upgrading to Celery 4.x due to the [Django ORM broker having been removed](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#features-removed-for-lack-of-funding). Are there any message queues that don't require any local setup (or can be pip-installed) and separate launching?